# Checkbox bind CHANGE event

Tags: jquery, events, bind

I want to submit my form after a user clicked/touched the checkbox:

THE HTML

```
<input type="checkbox" name="chkSales" id="chkSales" class="custom" data-inline="true" data-mini="true"/><label for="chkSales">Sales</label>                                         
<input type="checkbox" name="chkArrival" id="chkArrival" class="custom" data-inline="true" data-mini="true"/><label for="chkArrival">New Arrival</label>
```

​
The Js:

```
$("input[type='checkbox']").change(function() {
    alert(e);
    print(e);
});​
```

From what I read here it should really work, but id doenst! where is my problem?

(it should be change, since mobile devices don't click, they use touch...
http://jsfiddle.net/usTHG/2/

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
$("input[type='checkbox']").change(function(e) {
                                            ^---- you missed e here
    alert(e.type); 
    print(e);
});​
```

**[Working example](http://jsfiddle.net/usTHG/3/)**

Answer (score 3):

Try this please:

you are missing `e` in your function(`e`)

**code**

```
$("input[type='checkbox']").change(function(e) {
    alert(e);
    print(e);
});​
```

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $("input[type='checkbox']").change(function(e) {
            alert(e);
            print(e);
        });
    });
```