# How to bind unique event to every checkbox?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Using angular, I create a keypress-bindning everytime a checkbox is checked, and remove the bindning when it is unchecked.

```
$scope.checked = function(task){
    if(task){
        $document.bind('keypress', function(event){
            console.log(event);
        })
    }else{
        $document.unbind('keypress');   
    }
}
```

My problem is, that I have more than one checkbox, I want to create a unique event for each keypress. How can I do this?

Comment: what do you mean by create a unique event for each keypress? separate functions should be called on each keypress event fired?

Comment: If one checkbox is unchecked, all other checkboxes should still listen for the keypress. Each function will also get the value from the checkbox.

Comment: do you really need a `keypress`? or just like @user1708762 suggested, the `change` event should do

Comment: the workflow is, #1 check one or more boxes, #2 push a button to perform actions based on what boxes are being checked. Not sure how the change-event will solve this?

Comment: is this automated or user-driven?

Comment: it is user driven. For example, the might click a checkbox and press "p" to postpone. or click a checkbox and press "c" for complete.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49561/discussion-between-anurupr-and-kristoffer-nolgren)

Answer (score 0):

Add 'id' attribute to all of them and assign them differnt 'id' and then run a loop based on 'id' and bind the 'change' event to each checkbox.

After that follow this -

[Checkbox bind CHANGE event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11114056/checkbox-bind-change-event)

Comment: how do I bind an event to a checkbox? Will the keypress still trigger globaly?